# Can't open Android Studio in Ubuntu 20.04 in XMonad desktop environment

Tags: 20.04, android, android-studio, xmonad

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and I am trying to open android studio in xmonad desktop environment, which is a tiling window manager written in haskell, but the GUI doesn't load properly. It just shows blank screen. If I open Android Studio in default Ubuntu desktop environment, it loads correctly. I have started using Tilling window manager as my daily workflow and I don't want to switch back and forth to ubuntu to work in android studio. Any solution for the above problem?

Comment: The solution is to use GNOME probably.

Comment: @Christian I want to open it in xmonad and don't want to shift to GNOME.

Comment: You are not alone. Many users complain over Android Studio not working in XMonad and DWM, It seems better to use Gnome, KDE or Mate when running Android Studio. Some users that work with professional Android development ditch XMonad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I am running android-studio from terminal and only had to set the _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING variable to 1 before launching it.

```
export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1
```

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: also worked for me, both ubuntu and nixos